# How to know server is in good health condition or not?

Tags: response

How can I know that my server is working fine i.e in good health condition.

My Requirement is Users are complaining that they can not access the web application (Web site) something like it taking long time to do, some times its not completing the request.

I want to know whether my web site is in good condition or not before users and to get  an alert message.

I want to know how we can measure whether the server is very responsive or user is not facing any problem. Some times my site takes long time coz. millions of data records have to be retrieved in that case I can not depend upon response time.

please help me on this

Comment: This is a very wide question. Have you some monitoring tools already? Do you care about web server only or the end user experience? Server health and web response time are two very different things. Your web server can be very healthy and your users getting bad response time because of network, database load, etc. You can start by measuring response time with tools like webinject.

Comment: @Floewnt I dont want to use any third party... User experience is my first priority and I like to know That if any network traffic disturbance also..  If user is having any problem I need an alert In that alert I like to know response time, services status in server and etc ..

Comment: ok, see my answer below. Webinject is a perl script easy to use that may help you. It can be used with monitoring tools like Nagios, but you are not required to.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring response time without any third party software can be done with scripts like [webinject](http://www.webinject.org/). Webinject is a perl script that execute some browsing scenario and tells you if it acceptable or not.

Run a script at a regular interval, say 10min, that will start a webinject scenario. If the scenario is ko (check the return code of your webinject call), your script can send you an email, a sms, start a sound alarm, ... whatever is relevant to you.

You can also add some complexity by running a diagnostic script (check network by pinging relevant hardware, check cpu/ram usage of your servers, check the number of sessions in your database, ...) and send the diagnostic by email. You can also save the response times in a database (like a rdd database) to have a graphical view and be able to do some problem analysis on it.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution .. I need that in JAVA